# QGIS - Polygon - Modify One side with exact Measure

Tags: qgis, polygon

I have a polygon and I want to change the measure of one side with an exact dimension.

[image]

In this example one side has 2m, but I want to be 1m.

I know that with advanced digitizing you can modify the length by saying how much you want to increase or decrease that side. To do that you need to know the length of that side.
I would like to find a solution without having to know that length.

Comment: Can you please show the image of this procedure?

Comment: @Taras have updated the information